# Game Boy interrupt handler crashes unless I jump to it indirectly

Tags: assembly, 8080, game-boy

I have an interrupt handler I created, which is meant to reduce the overhead of interrupts as much as possible. Setting up the interrupt handler is done while interrupts are disabled, of course. It starts as a function call that takes a number in the accumulator as an argument and through a series of lookup tables, selects an interrupt routine in ROM and copies it to the RAM area at `&A000`. I chose to copy it to RAM so that the interrupt vector for the LCDSTAT interrupt can just `JP &A000` and the rest will be handled by the interrupt handler in RAM. It works as expected... except for the part where the interrupt vector contains `JP &A000`. That crashes the game, and the crash screen shows that the program counter has "escaped" and started executing RAM. What's puzzling about this is that if I have the interrupt vector jump to another label, and THAT label contains nothing except `JP &A000`, it works fine! Literally the only thing I changed to fix it was adding a second jump that does nothing but slow down the interrupt handler, and that seems to fix it. Could someone explain why?

Example code, in case this question doesn't make sense:

```
    org &0048                 ;Interrupt:   LCD-Stat
        jp InterruptDispatch  ;in theory this is no different than JP &A000 except being 10 cycles slower, yet
                              ;the game crashes if I jump to &A000 here.


;many many lines of code later

InterruptDispatch:
        jp &A000
```

Edit: I've found that 3 `NOP`s before the `JP &A000` also does the trick. I've tested my ROM on both Visual Boy Advance and BGB, and both exhibit similar results: an interrupt that jumps directly to cartridge RAM will result in undefined behavior (i.e. the program counter escaping past the RAM area and `NOP`-sliding to the Game Boy's work ram) unless the jump to cartridge RAM is delayed by at least 10 cycles. I've never seen this documented anywhere and I have no way of testing this on real hardware. Is this a known quirk of the game boy?

EDIT 2: I've nearly narrowed it down to one cause: my wait for vBlank routine: From the [PanDocs](https://gbdev.io/pandocs/Reducing_Power_Consumption.html):

> A better example would be a procedure as shown below. In this case the VBlank interrupt must be enabled, and your VBlank interrupt handler must set vblank_flag (a one-byte variable allocated in RAM) to a non-zero value.

```
  ld   hl, vblank_flag  ; hl = pointer to vblank_flag
  xor  a                ; a = 0
.wait
  halt                  ; suspend CPU - wait for ANY enabled interrupt
  cp   a, [hl]          ; is the vblank_flag still zero?
  jr   z, .wait         ; keep waiting if zero
  ld   [hl], a          ; set the vblank_flag back to zero
```

I had used this routine to wait for vBlank just after enabling the interrupt that caused the crash. Removing this got rid of the problem. However, I did not have this exact code in-line after enabling interrupts. Rather, I `CALL`ed this as a subroutine and it looked like this:

```
  push hl
  ld   hl, vblank_flag  ; hl = pointer to vblank_flag
  xor  a                ; a = 0
.wait
  halt                  ; suspend CPU - wait for ANY enabled interrupt
  cp   a, [hl]          ; is the vblank_flag still zero?
  jr   z, .wait         ; keep waiting if zero
  ld   [hl], a          ; set the vblank_flag back to zero
  pop hl
  ret
```

I've found that if I run the vBlank Wait procedure in-line, with no push/pop HL and no ret, but make no other changes, there is no crash when the interrupt at &0048 immediately jumps to &A000.

**TL;DR:**
If the [PanDocs' recommended vBlank-wait procedure](https://gbdev.io/pandocs/Reducing_Power_Consumption.html) is `CALL`ed, preserving HL, just after enabling an interrupt that jumps to cartridge RAM, the program counter will skip the cartridge ram entirely unless the jump to cartridge ram is delayed by at least 10 cycles. Why is this?

Comment: Are you using an emulator that produces this error message?

Comment: As the 8080 doesn't support position-independent code, how do you copy/relocate the ISR to its new run adress? Are you making sure you relocate the addresses?

Comment: I'm relocating it, using a pseudo-LDIR to copy the code from ROM to RAM. I never use JPs in the copied ISR, only JRs. I may not have made this clear before, but the only difference between the program crashing and not crashing is whether I have a JP to &A000 at &0048, or a jump to another ROM location that immediately jumps to &A000 and does nothing else. So in theory there should be no difference between the two. But there is!

Comment: So, a "Z80" tag would probably be more fitting than the "8080" tag you currently have.

Comment: I guess I should reframe the question, the problem I'm having is understanding why jumping somewhere else and then immediately jumping to the ISR fixes the bug. That doesn't make sense, unless there's some hardware-specific reason that the cartridge RAM becomes inaccessible the moment an interrupt occurs but "refreshes" a few cycles later. That's my only guess as to what's going on here but I don't know if such a phenomenon exists. It seems as though I ruled out all possibilities of a mistake on my end.

Comment: You should also point out what emulator you're using (I guess you do) - I have a strong feeling that what you experience might simply be an emulator glitch.

Comment: It's BGB. I haven't tested it on other emulators so I'll try it on a different one later

Comment: @tofro Except it isn't a Z80 either.

Comment: When pointing to some external information, adding a link would be a good idea.

Comment: @Raffzahn I did in the main body but not in the TLDR version, I just fixed that now.

Comment: I tried creating a minimal example to replicate the problem without having all the extra fluff my program comes with, but I couldn't get the bug to happen again! So it's most likely a mistake I made on my part. Oh well. Still never figured it out

Comment: @puppydrum64 I'm intrigued by this and would look to troubleshoot it further for hardware research. Do you still have a copy of the ROM as it were when you observed this problem? A newer version might also do since I might be able to glean something from the code structure.

Comment: I don't think I do anymore, unfortunately. I can try to re-create it but I can't remember what I was doing at the time.